# Comma needed after "months"?

Tags: commas

Is a comma needed after the word "months" in the following sentence?

> Over the course of several months he was subjected to a battery of diagnostic tests and assessments.

Thank you!

Comment: No, why would you think a comma is needed there?

Comment: You seem to have problems with some very basic comma usage, maybe they belong in [ell.se]?

Comment: Generally speaking, a comma would be used after *months*. This is because the first five words act as an introductory clause to the sentence. However, with short introductory phrases (generally of four words or less), a comma is optional. This particular phrase falls into a grey area. But using a comma is never wrong. On the other hand, omitting a comma often can be.

Comment: HI Barner, I like to gain insight and perspective from others.